# How to make PyCharm work with the Go plugin?

Tags: plugins, go, pycharm

I am using PyCharm 3.1.1 and I have installed the [Go plugin for IntelliJ Idea](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin).  I did `export GOROOT=$(go env GOROOT)` to prevent PyCharm from complaining about missing `GOROOT` environment variable.

Now I was able to create a sample project, but the run command complains:

> Error running untitled1.go: No Go Sdk defined for this project

On other sites I found that I should do something like:

> Go to the `File -> Project Structure` and configure Go SDK by clicking `+` button and
>   selecting `/usr/lib/go/` folder.

But I don't have `File -> Project Structure` menu item.

How to make PyCharm work with the Go plugin?

Comment: Personally I keep a separate IDEA for the golang plugin, and not mix PyCharm with the Go plugin. Do you have a reason to keep them together other than saving disk space?

Comment: I use PyCharm for Python development. It would be nice to have everything in one place. If it's not possible - I'll use a separate IDEA

Comment: You could try to start with a fresh IDEA and then add both Python as a plugin and Go as a plugin.

Comment: I have a license for PyCharm, and I think the community version does not have all the features.

Comment: What it lacks is mainly framework integration (django, etc). Code analysis, debugging, completion etc - all work perfectly. I used to have the commercial version and I found that I don't really need any of the features the community version is missing so I didn't renew my license.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I will try to install IDEA with Python and Go plugins

Answer (score 3):

You can get most of the way there with External Tools.  There is no way to replace the 'Run' button until the next version of the plug-in, per [Issue #728](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/issues/728).

To set up your external tools, go to PyCharm -> Preferences (command+,) -> Tools -> External Tools -> +

Fill in the form:
[image]

Hit OK.  Use it from the menus:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it now with a [Version 2016.1 or higher](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/). I will give a complete guide, so the first steps would not be relevant for you. Also I write it using MacOS, so some names might be different. Go to

`Preferences -> Plugins -> Browse Repositories -> Manage repositories` and insert `https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugins/alpha/5047` which is the [plugin behind this repo](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin) (maintained by IntelliJ). Install that plugin.

After plugin is installed, create a `.go` file. When you open it you will see a popup `go project sdk is not defined`. Click on it and select your `/usr/local/go` path.

A couple of helpful links:

- [go plugin documentation](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/wiki/Documentation)
- [how to set up go plugin](https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/setting-google-go-plugin-intellij-idea-13-os-x-10-8-5)

Answer (score 1):

Please use the latest release from Github releases https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/releases. It supports PyCharm 4.0.5+.

Answer (score 0):

If you are an IntelliJ  fan, you can edit and run Go using *goland* editor (Notice, this is **not** a Go plugin added to PyCharm but a different editor).

For installation on Ubontu:
`sudo snap install goland --classic` , or visit there website https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/install-and-set-up-product.html

Answer (score -3):

If you're running on OS X, you'll have to use the `launchctl setenv` command to set the `GOROOT` environment variable, so it's available system wide, which includes launching applications via the GUI

```
launchctl setenv GOROOT $(go env GOROOT)
```

To check it's set

```
launchctl getenv GOROOT
```

For the values to persist across reboots, you'll need to edit (or create) `/etc/launchd.conf`:

```
setenv GOROOT [path]
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3756686/12606) for more information of the format of this file. Note that you won't be able to call $(go env GOROOT) within launchd.conf

Comment: The question is not about about `GOROOT` environment variable. It's about PyCharm vs IDEA

Comment: Why then does is the last statement in the article "How to make PyCharm work with Google Go language plugin?" and the title of the question is "Google Go language plugin with PyCharm"

Comment: The question was not about environment variables. It was how to set up Go SDK in PyCharm.