# How can I install Go Plugin in PyCharm Professional (2023.3.1)?

Tags: go, plugins, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I tried following the steps from this other question: [How to make PyCharm work with the Go plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928364/how-to-make-pycharm-work-with-the-go-plugin?newreg=b6610b7c316449b892711dc3ac1452c7)

However, the link https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugins/alpha/5047 shows me an error in PyCharm. I also tried following the steps from the repo itself https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin

Anybody faced this problem?

I tried the StackOverflow post, as well as the repo (both links). But it seems like it can't find the plugin in the link provided. I have professional license for PyCharm, that's why I want to use it for Go as well.

Comment: I think you're out of luck. [JetBrains marketplace](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5047-go-language-golang-org-support-plugin) says the plugin isn't compatible with PyCharm and the GitHub repository hasn't been maintained in 6 years. Last comment on the JetBrains site about that plugin was in 2019... Why not use [GoLand](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/)?